# Error in sparseMatrix(i = x[["indices"]][] + 1, p = x[["indptr"]][], x = x[["data"]][], : 'dims' must contain all (i,j) pairs

Tags: r, seurat, scanpy

I have successfully converted a h5ad file to a h5seurat with

```
Convert("xxx.h5ad","h5seurat",overwrite = TRUE)
```

but when I tried to use the `LoadH5Seurat` function from SeuratDisk R package, I got error messages like this:

> Validating h5Seurat file
> Initializing RNA with data
> Error in sparseMatrix(i = x[["indices"]][] + 1, p = x[["indptr"]][], x = x[["data"]][],  :
> 'dims' must contain all (i,j) pairs
> and my code is 'LoadH5Seurat("xxxx.h5seurat",assays ='RNA')'

Has anyone met the same error?
Any suggestions will be really helpful!

```
library(SeuratDisk)
Convert("xxx.h5ad","h5seurat",overwrite = TRUE)
seuratobj <- LoadH5Seurat("xxxx.h5seurat",assays ='RNA')
```